# How to increment Values with buttons on Arduino UNO

Tags: increment, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm doing a project for uni using an Arduino and part of it involves making a a sort of menu where a pushbutton (or pushbuttons) are used to switch between cases. Each case has a specific LED bound to it so the user knows what option they have selected, the code can be seen below. What ends up happening is all the LEDS turn on instead of just one at at a time and the button ends up doing nothing. I can turn on individual LEDS by changing the selection value and I've run the same button set up on other code so its not a hardware issue. I'm not amazing at programming but it looks like it should work so am I missing something really simple?

```
`
#define buttonPin A3 // Input Push Button

int selection = 0; // value used for selection 

void setup() {
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

if(buttonPin, HIGH){
       selection++;
    }

  switch(selection){

    case 0:
      digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
    break;

    case 1:
      digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
    break;
    
     case 2:
      digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
    break;

     case 3:
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
    break;

     case 4:
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
    break;
   
    }

    

}
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you increase the selection you should add a test for maximum and decide there if to reverse the order (selection--) or to start from zero.

Also, you need to turn off all non selected leds.

[EDIT]

Looking at your edited code there are few issues I would like to point:

1. The debouncer blocks your code, check out [millis()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) as a way to count time while doing other tasks.
2. I always [PULLUP](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/pinmode/) my inputs and check for LOW state to determine a pushed button (there are tons of discussions about that so I will not go into details).
3. As shown below, using an array for the led pins will simplify your code.

....

```
const int buttonPin_up = 7;
const int buttonPin_down = 8;
int selection = 0; // value used for selection

// Using an array will simplify the program and will allow you to select any pin
// even if it's not in a sequence of numbers (and still use a FOR loop to handle it)
int led[] = {2,3,4,5,6};

// Get the number of elements in the array
const int numOfLeds = sizeof(led) / sizeof(led[0]);

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin_up, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin_down, INPUT);

  for (int i=0; i<numOfLeds; i++) {
    pinMode(led[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin_up) == HIGH) {
    selection += 1;
    delay(750);
  }
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin_down) == HIGH) {
    selection -= 1;
    delay(750);
  }
  
  if (selection > 4) {
    selection = 0;
  }
  
  if (selection < 0) {
    selection = 4;
  }

  for (int i=0; i<numOfLeds; i++) {
    bool state = LOW;
    if (i == selection) state = HIGH;
    digitalWrite(i, state);
  }
}
```

....

Comment: Hi Nino, Thanks for the reply, I changed the selection section to this  but now only 1 led is on (case 0, led 2)                                         '                      
if(buttonPin, HIGH){
  selection++;
       if(selection<5){
        selection = 0;
       }
    }

Comment: Please update your question with the lastest code.

Comment: Will post updated code later tonight, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Several points to address.

1. Why are you not using `digitalRead()` to check the status of the pin? You should NOT be doing this:

> `if(buttonPin, HIGH)`

The correct way to do this is by checking the status of the digital pin via `digitalRead()`, as follows:

`if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) { // Add your logic here }`

2. NEVER use an analog pin (A3) as a digital input. You are declaring a pin connected to the ADC module as an input, which will lead to erratic behavior.

I would rather use `const int`:

`const int pinButton = 3; // used 3 as an example here, referring to digital pin 3, not A3.`

3. The most obvious reason why you will see all LEDs lighting up is that you are facing [contact chatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce) with no debouncing routine for your switch. The implemented logic is flawed, I'm afraid, and due to the chattering, the value of *selection* rapidly increases, 'telling' the switch-case to light up the LEDs.

You mentioned that your circuit will have multiple push-buttons. Why using a single variable (*selection*) to decide which will turn on then?

Add more buttons, use the [Bounce](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Bounce/) library and be careful reading pin states and distinguishing between analog and digital pins.

4. If the number of push-buttons is large, consider arranging them in a matrix-type of keyboard and use the [Keypad](https://github.com/Chris--A/Keypad) library

Comment: Hi Daniel Thanks for the reply, I knew I was making some silly mistakes thank you for showing me where to look. Currently working on other aspects of the project but will try to implement these ideas later tonight. I was using the analogue pins as I was already using a lot of the digital pins for other things but should have enough to change them over and one of my supervisors did mention something about the debouncing of the pushbuttons so will look into implementing that. I was only has the one button assigned aswell just to test the increment but only using 2 so don't think the Library is -

Comment: necessary for my project but will bear that in mind for future use. Apologies for my late reply as well

Answer (score 0):

I've Managed to crack it Thanks for your suggestions! There may be ways to shorten the code some what but in its current state is fit for what I need it to do. May shorten the delay but its running well, thanks for bearing with me

```
const int buttonPin_up = 7;
const int buttonPin_down = 8;

int selection = 0; // value used for selection

void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin_up, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin_down, INPUT);
  
}

void loop() {

  if (digitalRead(buttonPin_up) == HIGH) {
    selection += 1;
    delay(750);
  }
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin_down) == HIGH) {
    selection -= 1;
    delay(750);
  }
    if (selection > 4) {
      selection = 0;
    }
    if (selection < 0) {
      selection = 4;
    }

  switch (selection) {

    case 0:                            
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
      break;

    case 1:
      digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
      break;

    case 2:
      digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
      break;

    case 3:
      digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(6, LOW);
      break;

    case 4:
      digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
      break;

  }

}
```

Comment: Glad to know that you got it to work. If any of our answers helped you to get your desired result, don't forget to mark them as answers.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I will do that now (sorry still new to the forum)

Comment: Nice progress, I added some info to my answer.